# Using Logical Indexing of first 2 elements in N-D array?

Tags: matlab

So I have a = rand(3,3,2).

Then I have a logical index that's something like

> > b = [1 0 0; 0 0 1; 1 1 1]

b =

```
 1     0     0
 0     0     1
 1     1     1
```

But I want to be able to call a(b) for both a(:,:,1) and a(:,:,2). Both a(:,:,1) and a(:,:,2) have shared logical indices. How would I be able to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `b` is a logical array then you can do

```
n = size(a, 3);

a(repmat(b, [1,1,n]))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a1 = a(:,:,1);
a2 = a(:,:,2);

selected_a1 = a1(b==1);
selected_a2 = a2(b==1);
```

Here, we select all values of matrix a where b is 1 and then store them into selected_a1, and selected_a2.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `b` is a logical array (if it's not, then convert by doing `b = logical(b);`), then try the following:

```
a([b(:); b(:)])
```